# MagicalRecord iCloud issues

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

I am TRYING to use MagicalRecord with iCloud and every time I call

```
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:nil localStoreNamed:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
```

for the first time I get these logs below...has anyone seen this before.  I have cleaned the project and deleted the app, but I am getting it every time.

I can see my app in Settings>iCloud, but nothing in the developer.icloud.com documents folder

```
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.247 MyApp[6902:5d17] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    Confused by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.248 MyApp[6902:5807] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    Confused by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.253 MyApp[6902:1507] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/.stage.nosync/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    Confused by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.259 MyApp[6902:1507] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=/staging.nosync
    Confused by: staging.nosync
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.261 MyApp[6902:1507] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore
    Confused by: iCloudStore
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.263 MyApp[6902:1507] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/metadata.store-wal
    Confused by: metadata.store-wal
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.274 MyApp[6902:170b] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/Data.nosync/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY=/baseline.model
    Confused by: baseline.model
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.279 MyApp[6902:1413] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/metadata.store-shm
    Confused by: metadata.store-shm
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.286 MyApp[6902:170b] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/mobile.DDDDDD-DDDD-DDDD-DDDD-DDDDDDDDD/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    Confused by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.291 MyApp[6902:170b] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=/baseline.zip
    Confused by: baseline.zip
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.292 MyApp[6902:1413] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/SyncData/com.walshitech.sbrspeeds/ClientDevices/ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZ
    Confused by: ZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZ
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.297 MyApp[6902:1413] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=/baseline.meta
    Confused by: baseline.meta
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.298 MyApp[6902:170b] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=/staging.nosync/iCloudStore.sqlite
    Confused by: iCloudStore.sqlite
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.306 MyApp[6902:5d17] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/Data.nosync/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY=/baseline.meta
    Confused by: baseline.meta
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.310 MyApp[6902:5d17] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/Data.nosync/.baseline/iCloudStore/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY=/baseline.zip
    Confused by: baseline.zip
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.315 MyApp[6902:170b] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/metadata.store
    Confused by: metadata.store
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.315 MyApp[6902:1507] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY
    Confused by: mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.324 MyApp[6902:1507] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/SyncData/com.walshitech.sbrspeeds/Information/DeletedDocuments
    Confused by: DeletedDocuments
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.324 MyApp[6902:5d17] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=/baseline.model
    Confused by: baseline.model
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.324 MyApp[6902:170b] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/SyncData/com.walshitech.sbrspeeds/Information/DeletedClients
    Confused by: DeletedClients
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.325 MyApp[6902:1413] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/SyncData/com.walshitech.sbrspeeds/ClientDevices/YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYY5
    Confused by: YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYY5
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.328 MyApp[6902:5807] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/.stage.nosync/iCloudStore
    Confused by: iCloudStore
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.330 MyApp[6902:1507] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=/baseline.gcmodel
    Confused by: baseline.gcmodel
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.330 MyApp[6902:5207] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    Confused by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.346 MyApp[6902:5d17] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/iCloudStore
    Confused by: iCloudStore
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.348 MyApp[6902:5207] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData/.cdmetadata/metadata.nosync/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY/iCloudStore/CCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCC.cid
    Confused by: CCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCC.cid
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.349 MyApp[6902:5d17] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/Data.nosync/.baseline/iCloudStore/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY=/mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY
    Confused by: mobile.YYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYY
    2013-02-13 09:25:56.358 MyApp[6902:5207] +[PFUbiquityLocation createUbiquityLocationForPath:withUbiquityRootPath:](821): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to continue parse components of URL: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/Data.nosync/.baseline/current.nosync/iCloudStore/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY=/baseline.gcmodel
    Confused by: baseline.gcmodel
```

Comment: Wow, I've seen tons of different iCloud errors but that's a new one on me. All I could guess at is that maybe the `iCloudData`, `SyncData`, etc directories don't exist and iCloud is barfing because of that. Just a guess, though.

Comment: Yep, I don't know how to get around this one.  Since I am using MagicalRecord, hard to determine if the issue is that code or iCloud being overly hard to work with.  I think the latter.

Comment: Tom:  Any way I can force create those directories in iCloud?

Comment: The usual way would be to get the location of the ubiquity directory using `-[NSFileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:]`, and then create the directories using normal `NSFileManager` calls. I don't know if Magical Record is supposed to take care of this for you. You could check on it by logging in to the iCloud account at http://developer.icloud.com/ to see if they exist.

Comment: After some test, I created the directories, still go the same issue.  I am surprised no one has seen this before.  I changed the logic to use this, but still no luck:    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"XXXX.com.company.myapp" localStoreNamed:@"MyApp.sqlite"];

Answer (score 2):

I know this a old question but for the people that just came across the issue, I think I found the solution. For me this was an issue with the simulator. Apparently the simulator creates some weird files the device cannot properly access.

Try doing the following in the following order and see if it goes away:

1. Delete your app from the iOS Simulator and the devices and you have installed it on.
2. On your iPhone / iPad (**not** the simulator), go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage > Your_app_name > Edit (top right) > Delete All.
3. Try installing the app again on your **device**.

Hopefully the weird errors will no longer be there. Running the app on the simulator again though will probably create them all over again and you will have to repeat the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

well i can tell you what they are,  but not a guaranteed solution though.

those files are what i'll call,  "ghost files"  that were created by you or your app in the ubiquity directory.

to show that this is what is happening go to your "mobile documents" folder in your user library on your Mac,  go to the "/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/XXXXXXXXXXX~com~my~app/iCloudData"  file  and simply create a new file by the "command N"  by hand.

then from then on you will get an extra "error"  with "untitled folder" as the file it can not "parse"...

deleting everything from your device seems to leave these files on the actual iCloud data servers though (I think).  creating "ghost files"

if this is a developer account,  you can see and even possibly delete them by going to:

https://developer.icloud.com/   and logging in with your developer iD.

if this was a test account instead,   then it appears to be no way that i can find to delete those files..

you can get around it by simply creating new directories in your code,  so instead of the word "iCloudData"   make up a new one "iCloudData2" or something,

and you can now get iCloud working again,  however,  you will continue to see these warning/errors in your console...

if someone figures out how to delete them from a test user account  "in other words a none developer iD"  let me know...

it used to be that you could go to the above website and put in your test user iD's but in Apple's infinite wisdom, they changed that to only be developer ID's now as of a couple months ago.